# HTML cannot locate my js files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a MEAN app. When i try to link my app.min.js file from index.html the console gives this error "http://localhost:8080/app.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED"

Ive tried all types of paths, like adding "/", "../" etc and none of them worked. I thought it might be to do with express static file paths so tried the same but no luck. Any other threads for similar issues did not fix it.

Heres the code:

server.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));
app.use(express.static('\build'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../index.html'));
});

console.log('Server running: http://localhost:8080')
app.listen(8080);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularApp">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="public/ico/favicon.ico"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="app.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ui-view></ui-view>

    </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "angular-scripts",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "description": "Simple AngularJS Boilerplate to kick start your new project with SASS support and Gulp watch/build tasks",
  "author": "Semianchuk Vitalii",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.0",
    "angular": "^1.6.5",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-messages": "^1.6.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chalk": "*",
    "cross-spawn": "*",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "fs-extra": "*",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-csso": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongojs": "^2.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.8",
    "path": "*",
    "path-exists": "*"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'public/**/*.scss',
        'src/modules/**/*.scss'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('style.js'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('compress-dev', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.8/angular-messages.js',
        'app.js',
        'src/**/*.js',
    ])
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('compress-prod', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        'node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'app.js',
        'src/**/*.js',
    ])
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/styles/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('src/modules/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js', ['compress-dev']);
    gulp.watch('app.js', ['compress-dev']);
});

gulp.task('dev',  ['sass', 'compress-dev', 'scripts', 'watch']);
gulp.task('build', ['sass', 'compress-prod']);
```

Heres my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG1ZS.jpg)

Comment: is the app.min.js located in build ??? does it gets created

Comment: did you try  <script src="../build/app.min.js "></script>

Comment: Yeah i tried that path also. See the attached screenshot of my project structure. The app.min.js file is there. It actually happens when i try to link any js files.

Comment: how did you get app.min.js ... webpack , gulp or a readymade ? can you share package.json

Comment: Its built with gulp, but its not just app.min.js file that it canot find, its any js file that i link with the script tag. Updated with package.json

Comment: did it work with the scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

Add some scripts to *package.json* ..it will do the required script creation

```
 "scripts": {
    "prestart" : "gulp",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "server": "gulp server",
    "serverbuild": "gulp server-build"
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it made no difference. Even if i take gulp out alltogether, it still cant find any js files that i link from the index file.

Comment: the gulpfile.js please show that ..... i want to see to what destination is the file getting created to...so that I can  **<script src="/build/app.min.js"></script>**

Comment: ahaaa there is no *default* task...  to the  gulpfile.js  add  **gulp.task('default',  ['sass', 'compress-dev', 'scripts', 'watch']);**   and try again

Comment: That still didnt work im afraid. Im relatively new to gulp, but my understanding is that you dont have to use it if you are referencing js and css directly from the index.html file. Its only a tool that helps automate minification and other tasks.

The main problem is that when i try to link .js or .css files from my index.html file, it gives that error. Even if it remove gulp completely and ignore the min.js file.

Comment: I reverted back to an earlier commit and it works again. I tried to figure out what was different but couldnt quite see. Thanks for your help anyway.